# Cannot get the most basic of Backbone.js "Hello World" examples to work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to learn Backbone.js.  The problem is that I am unable to run even the most simple of examples available from online tutorials (e.g. http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/1.html).  The only thing I can think of is that most of the tutorials were written around Backbone 0.3.x.  Current version is 0.9.x.  I would be extremely grateful if someone could elaborate on why the following is not working.

backbone_test.js:

```js
(function($){

  // **ListView class**: Our main app view.
  var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({    
    el: $('body'), // attaches `this.el` to an existing element.
    // `initialize()`: Automatically called upon instantiation. Where you make all types of bindings, _excluding_ UI events, such as clicks, etc.
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // fixes loss of context for 'this' within methods

       this.render(); // not all views are self-rendering. This one is.
    },
    // `render()`: Function in charge of rendering the entire view in `this.el`. Needs to be manually called by the user.
    render: function(){
      $(this.el).append("<ul> <li>hello world</li> </ul>");
    }
  });

  // **listView instance**: Instantiate main app view.
  var listView = new ListView();      

})(jQuery);
```

backbone_test.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./backbone_test.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="backbone_test.css">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually, when i pasted your code into a jsFiddle it worked perfectly
though i can imaging some issues rising up if you move your code around outside of your jquery's document ready function.

so i made a few suggestions here:

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({    
  el: 'body', // i gave a reference to the el, not the jquery object but the selector itself.

  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // fixes loss of context for 'this' within methods
    this.setElement($(this.el)); // backbone 0.9.1 code, re-setting the element of your view this time, i set it to the $() jquery object of your selector  this.el.
    this.render(); // not all views are self-rendering. This one is.
  },

  // 
  render: function(){
    // and here instead of $(this.el) i use the cached jquery object of your view, this is also backbone 0.9.1 stuff.
    this.$el.append("<ul> <li>hello world</li> </ul>");
  }
});


// jquery's document ready function only to be used for firing up the application
(function($){

  // you still instantiate your listview once here
  var listView = new ListView();      

})(jQuery);​
```

however even with these changes, your code still worked,
you can verify that in this jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/YZR9v/

Comment: I think you're right, `el: $('body')` is the root of the problem as `ListView` isn't defined inside a `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: That was it.  Encapsulated everything in a document ready call back and it now works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for me it worked when I changed the js version in the index html to the listed below, basically I'm using the same code as the tutorial, but instead loading the scripts suggested on it, I used the js versions suggested in the code example of the question by Benjen

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

The code that I copied-pasted is in this link: http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/1.html 
I tried changing the code to the suggested above, but I couldn't make it work.

summary

jquery
 from 1.6.1  to 1.7.1

underscore
from 1.1.6 to 1.3.1

backbone
from 1.1.0 to  0.9.1 (*)

(*) I know is the older version but it worked for me to run the tutorial example